# Date/Time not coming properly in csv when written from bash

Tags: excel, bash, shell, csv

I am writing a comma(,) separated data from a .txt file to a .csv in bash.

**Part of the bash code which does this.**

```
   <path to file>/textfile.txt > <path to file>/csvfile.csv
```

All the data gets written in csv file properly except the data having date/time.

**Given input in text file :**

```
07/01/2021 00:22:21.948,LC firm
07/01/2021 00:31:01.975,5800
```

**Written CSV file :**

[CSV screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyBBH.png)

The written date/time shows a bit proper if we click the cell and see the formula bar but by default its showing differently in the cell. I dont want the value in the cell or in the formula bar.

**I want it to be in the below format while written to csv.**

```
07/01/2021 00:22:21.948 - with milliseconds

or

7/1/2021 12:22:21.948 AM - with milliseconds
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any bash code in your question.....

Comment: @user1934428 If you can see the first line of my question, this line - .../textfile.txt > .../csvfile.csv.. is from my bash script.

Comment: This is the **fragment** of a bash command.Not something we can reasonably discuss.

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah right! This is the only fragment which writes a txt file to csv file. So, the discussion here would be to do any changes to the txt file data which has got that date/time value using bash before writing it to csv so that the we could get the desired value written to csv

Comment: There s no command here! If I just type `textfile.txt >csvfile`, this would be valid only if `textfile.txt` were an executable, but then you would need to provide details about this executable. If it is not an executable, then there is nothing to execute. Also, the three periods in front of `textfile.txt` don't look like sensible bash to me.

Comment: @user1934428 Aww.. Sorry for those 3 dots.. I was just trying to mean that there were some path given to that file before the filenames. removed them if it was confusing.

Comment: Still, the information you give is incomplete.

Comment: @user1934428 To make it simple, I want to write the data from txt file to csv as a part of a bash script and when I do it, the date/time format is different in the written csv file. I want some help in manipulating the date/time data in the given txt file before writing it in the csv, so that the data will be written in appropriate format in the csv file.

Comment: Still I would like to see which command you are using **now** to write the file.

Comment: @user1934428 I am not sure if you were the only one not understanding my question and downvoting it but the others really understood well. Infact Raman Sailopal had understood very well and replied back with the expected piece of code as answer.

Comment: @Tracer. If you could kindly therefore accept the answer, It would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F, '{ hr=substr($0,12,2);if (hr<=12) { ampm="AM" } else { ampm="PM" };$1=$1" "ampm" - With Miliseconds";OFS="," }1' txtfile.txt > csvfile.csv
```

Set comma as the field seperator and then extract the hour from the line with substr. Check the hr variable to discover whether it is at or before 12 and if so, set the variable ampm to AM otherwise ampm is PM. Modify the first field accordingly and print the lines.

Output:

```
07/01/2021 00:22:21.948 AM - With Miliseconds,LC firm
07/01/2021 00:31:01.975 AM - With Miliseconds,5800
```

Comment: Thanks for checking on this. I tried your code and it works perfectly fine but only the first line have issues like its appending the 2nd column with the first one.

https://pasteboard.co/JIFuMIz.png

Comment: Can you make sure that there is a comma on the first line of the txt file?

Comment: No..I meant to say that, In the first row where I have highlighted in Red, it appended the 2nd column value with the 1st column and giving it in first column.

Output should be like this https://pasteboard.co/JIFxuVD.png

Comment: Yes. Comma is there on the first line of the txt file

Comment: It's applying the same logic to every line and so there must be something odd in the text file for line 1 (line 2 if you take account of the headers)

Comment: yes. line 2 to be precise in excel and line 1 in txt file. But, I think I can sort that out. Thanks again for helping on this :)